# Dj Rest Auth custom registration not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

I am using DJ-REST-AUTH for user registration API. I want the first_name and last_name to show in the API endpoint however right now it is just showing the default.[image: current API endpoint]

I have tried to configure the settings and create CustomRegisterSerializer. I read that I need to have a  def save(self, request) function as well and have tried to implement that as well.

main app
urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/authentication/', include('authentication.urls')),]
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = \[
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'dj_rest_auth',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',
    
    'authentication',]

SITE_ID = 1

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

)

REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'authentication.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer'
}

# Configure allauth to use email as username

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
```

authentication app

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from dj_rest_auth.views import (
LoginView, LogoutView, PasswordResetView, PasswordResetConfirmView
)
from .views import CustomRegisterView

urlpatterns = \[
path('register/', CustomRegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
path('passwordReset/', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
path('passwordResetConfirm/\<str:uidb64\>/\<str:token\>/',
PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
\]
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from dj_rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer

class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
first_name = serializers.CharField()
last_name = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2')
        
    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        return {
            'username': self.validated_data.get('username', ''),
            'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
            'password2': self.validated_data.get('password2', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'first_name': self.validated_data.get('first_name'),
            'last_name': self.validated_data.get('last_name'),
            
        }   
        
    def save(self, request):
        adapter = get_adapter()
        user = adapter.new_user(request)
        self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        user.save()
        adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
        return user
```

views.py

```
from dj_rest_auth.registration.views import RegisterView
from rest_framework import permissions

class CustomRegisterView(RegisterView):
permission_classes = \[permissions.AllowAny\]
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out the answer. I needed to specify the serializer on the view via serializer_class

```
from dj_rest_auth.registration.views import RegisterView
from rest_framework import permissions
from .serializers import CustomRegisterSerializer

class CustomRegisterView(RegisterView):
    serializer_class = CustomRegisterSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
```